# $\{4\}$: element vs. subset of $\{1,2, \{2\}, \{\{4\}\}\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

So i read a lot about this and I am a little bit confused if we have let's suppose $\{4\}$ then this is an element of the set $\{1,2, \{2\}, \{\{4\}\}\}$, but it is not a subset ?

Comment: I've tried to format, but I had to add a comma to your set. Please make sure it's correctly displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ! $\{ 4 \}$ is not an element of this set. But $\{ \{ 4\} \}$ is an element of this set; $\{ \{ \{ 4\} \} \}$ is a subset of this set.